# Why has it not become customary for people to wish each other "Good Yontiff" on Purim?

Tags: minhag, blessing, purim, megillat-esther

I can't recall people wishing each other "Gut Yuntiff" (or similar, like "Good Yom Tov") or any reference to Yom Tov on Purim. (Maybe someone does, but I'm unaware of this.)

Why don't people do this considering that Esther 9:19 and 9:22 both refer to the 14th day of Adar (Purim) as יום טוב?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26576/759

Comment: Somewhat similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50662

Answer (score 2):

If you notice passuk 9:22 is slightly changed and mentions that it turned from mourning to a good day,but the establishment for the future is only mishteh and simcha. Megillah daf 5b the gemara explains that hesped and taanis they accepted no to perform but to refrain from melacha they did not accept based off the two pessukim you mention and the discrepancy between them.